# What is a good strategy to generate and copy files atomically

Tags: linux, files

I have a file `myfile` that must be re-generated periodically. Re-generation takes some seconds. On the other hand, I have to periodically read the last (or next to last) file generated. What is the best way to guarantee that I am reading a completely generated file and that, once I begin reading it, I will be able to read it completely?

One possible solution is

1. `myfile` is actually a soft link to the last generated file, say `myfile.last`.
2. regeneration is done on a new file, say `myfile.new`
3. after regeneration, `myfile.new` is moved onto `myfile.last`

The problem I see (and I don't know the answer to) is: if another script is copying `myfile` while the mv takes place, does `cp` finish correctly?

Another possible solution would be to generate files with a timestamp on its name, say `myfile-2014-09-03_12:34` and `myfile` is again a soft link to the last created file. This link should be changed after creation to point to the new file. Again: what are the odds that something like

`cp myfile anotherfile`

copies a corrupted file?

Comment: `git` seems a good option for your case.

Comment: @Ramesh: it doesn't seem to be atomic, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4067287

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're moving within the same filesystem, `mv` is atomic -- it's just a rename, not copying contents. So if the last step of your generation is:

```
mv myfile.new myfile.last
```

The reading processes will always see either the old or new version of the file, never anything incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your first proposed solution:
regenerate the file into `myfile.new`, then rename (`mv`) it to `myfile`.

If you were *overwriting* `myfile` with the new data, an asynchronous reader
could get corrupt (or, at least, incomplete) data – but you know that already. 
I’m pretty sure that either of your proposed solutions would be safe. 
If another process opens the 12:34 version of the file at 12:38,
then it will continue to have *that file* open for reading
after you rename the 12:39 version of the file to `myfile`,
even though it no longer appears in any directory. 
This is even more clear-cut in the second case,
where the 12:34 version stays in the directory
after you change the symbolic link to point to the 12:39 file.